# How to avoid multiple node processes doing repetitive things?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a module in `Node.js` which repeatedly pick a document from MongoDB and process it. One document should be processed only once. I also want to use multiple processes concept. I want to run the same module(process) on different processors, which run independently.

The problem is, there might be a scenario where the same document picked and processed by two different workers. How multiple processes can know that, a particular document is processed by some other worker so I should not touch it. And there is no way that my independent processes can communicate. I cannot use a parent which forks multiple processes and acts as a bridge between them. How to avoid this kind of problems in Node.js?

Comment: add concurrency locking to [mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)

Comment: @lloyd The problem is not to anything with MongoDB concurrency, I believe. Two workers can read at different times if we enable concurrency locking. But they both should not process the same document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to assign an unique numeric ID to each of your MongoDB documents, and to assign an unique numeric identifier to each of your node.js workers.

For example, have an env var called NUM_WORKERS, and then in your node.js module:

```
var NumWorkers = process.env.NUM_WORKERS || 1;
```

You then need to assign an unique, contiguous instance number id (in the range 0 to NumWorkers-1) to each of your workers (e.g. via a command line parameter read by your node.js process when it initializes). You can store that in a variable called MyWorkerInstanceNum.

When you pick a document from MongoDB, call the following function (passing the document's unique documentId as a parameter):

```
function isMine(documentId){
    //
    // Example: documentId=10
    //          NumWorkers= 4
    // (10 % 4) = 2
    // If MyWorkerInstanceNum is 2, return true, else return false.
    return ((documentId % NumWorkers) === MyWorkerInstanceNum);
}
```

Only continue to actually process the document if isMine() returns true.
So, multiple workers may "pick" a document, but only one worker will actually process it.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Thanks. But if any worker died in between, we have to update the NumWorkers otherwise, documents assigned for it, won't be processed at all. It may cause problem if a process died and we don't know that happened.

Comment: You can use something like forever (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to make sure your node.js workers are always up. You just need to make sure to initialise each worker with the same instance number every time it re-initialises.

Comment: Great. It should work using that way. But currently, the `forever` thing and unique integer in the document, both don't exist in our application. I am trying to solve the problem with lesser changes.

Answer (score 1):

Simply keep a transaction log of the document being processed by its unique ID. In the transaction log table for the processed documents, write the status as one of the following (for example):

```
requested
initiated
processed
failed
```

You may also want a column in that table for stderr/stdout in case you want to know why something failed or succeeded, and timestamps - that sort of thing.

When you initialize the processing of the document in your Node app, look up the document by ID and check its status. If it doesn't exist, then you're free to process it.

Pseudo-code (sorry, I'm not a Mongo guy!):

```
db.collection.list('collectionName', function(err, doc) {
    db.collection.find(doc.id, 'transactions', function(err, trx) {
        if (trx === undefined || trx.status === 'failed') {
            DocProcessor.child.process(doc)
        } else {
            // don't need to process it, it's already been done
        }
    })
})
```

You'll also want to enable concurrency locking on the transactions log collection so that you ensure a row (and subsequent job) can't be duplicated. If this becomes a challenge to ensure docs are being queued properly, consider adding in an AMQP service to handle queuing of the docs. Set up a handler to manage distribution of the child processes and transaction logging. Flow would be something like:

MQ ⇢ Log ⇢ Handler ⇢ Doc processor children

Comment: What if two processes read transaction log at the same time and both don't find it's entry. They both will try to update the entry and starts processing it, right?

Comment: _That_ is where concurrency locking comes into play.

Comment: Process1 read, process2 read, process1 updated, process2 updated -> is that won't possible if we do concurrency locking? I don't believe so. Anyway need to check. Thank you

Comment: You're only doing concurrency locking on the _log_ itself, not the doc, or the doc collection. The log read/write will be milliseconds at most and should be plenty short enough to not block your I/O noticeably.

Comment: Yes. There must be a slight time delay between read, decide and write in log. That delay is enough to make another process to interfere, I think.

Comment: What about processing all the docs that come in, and only writing the output of the processed doc if there's no log entry (e.g. process first, do log check at the the end)? Depends how expensive processing the doc is. The other way you could handle this is by queuing the docs using ampq or something.

Comment: Yes, Processing the doc is very expensive. While processing, it will update the doc as well. AMQP queueing seems reasonable. One process should read and push it into the queue, and anyone can pick up and process it. That is what you are trying to say right? The document in mongodb is dynamic. It will be added by some other process. So, repeatedly picking and pushing to the queue also cannot avoid duplications, I think.

Comment: Yes, you got it. Queueing seems the most sensible way to avoid duplicate processing. That, coupled with a transaction log should get you what you need.

Comment: And yes, AMQP - it's my dyslexic day apparently 

Comment: Ha ha. For me too. Reading doc and pushing it to queue - how can this avoid duplications. I think, we are arriving at the same case again. same documents may be pushed one after one at the queue, can be received by two different workers, again the same transaction logging problem can occur :(

Comment: Only have one handler that spawns queues. MQ > log > handler > doc processor children. I've build something similar that worked great.

Comment: Yeah. A very good solution. If I can start writing from scratch I can do it. But, as I mentioned in the question, I cannot have a process which gives doc to children. This will make me rewrite the existing logic. I would like to solve the problem with making as minimal change as possible.